# UIImageView setImage does not change how image looks

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimageview

I am writing a tone generator UI and I need to change UIImageView image every time generator starts generating and finishes generating.
To do so I have

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *headphonesImage;
```

in my UIViewController. And I add default image to it like so

```
- (void) viewDidLoad
{
    ...
    headphonesImagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                             [UIImage imageNamed: @"Both Headphones"],
                             [UIImage imageNamed: @"Both Headphones Playing"],
                             nil];

    [self.headphonesImage setAlpha: 0.5];
    [self.headphonesImage setImage: headphonesImagesArray[0]];
    ...
}
```

My tone generator sends messages into this method

```
-   (void) toneGeneratorControllerStateHasChangedWithNotification: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    if([notification.name isEqualToString: ToneGenerationHasFinished])
        [self.headphonesImage setImage: headphonesImagesArray[0]];
    else
        [self.headphonesImage setImage: headphonesImagesArray[1]];
}
```

The problem is that though headphonesImage image changes to [1] and then nothing happens. I can see in variables inspector that headphonesImage image is changed every time the method is invoked, but these changes are not present on screen of neither simulator nor iPhone. I can't even hide this damn UIImageView. setHidden: true does nothing.

Please help!

Comment: `[self.headphonesImage setImage: headphonesImagesArray[0]]; ` is these method in viewDidLoad ?

Comment: @MShah The first one, yes.

Comment: Is the method `toneGeneratorControllerStateHasChangedWithNotification ` getting called ? have you checked that ? Put breakpoints within the method to confirm.

Comment: Put breakpoint after else part, to check whether its going into else or not.

Comment: @MShah It looks like yo do not understand what I've written above, so I shall explain. Yes, it does get called. multiple times, at exact moments when I need it to be called. In variables inspector using "Space" button I can see that the image changes from [0] to [1] and vice versa. But I do not see any difference on the screen.

Comment: i understand the code. i am not sure about the post method to which you have had added the observer to has correct parameter.

Comment: Where are your images stored? In assets or in bundle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"My tone generator sends messages into this method"

If *you* are writing the tone generator, it sounds like it is running on a background thread. You should send notifications on the main thread, especially if they trigger UI changes (such as setting an image), e.g.:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),^{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"toneGeneratorControllerStateHasChanged" 
                                                        object:nil 
                                                      userInfo:imageDict];
});
```

Alternatively, you can send the image change to the main thread as Igor suggests. The disadvantage there is having to do any time you use such notifications, as opposed to doing it in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Do this:-

```
-   (void) toneGeneratorControllerStateHasChangedWithNotification: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    if([notification.name isEqualToString: ToneGenerationHasFinished]) {
       self.headphonesImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Both Headphones"];
}
    else {
        self.headphonesImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Both Headphones Playing"];
}
}
```

instead of setImage.

Comment: let me know in case of issue

Comment: No difference whatsoever.

Comment: then check the image name in xcassets. If imageNamed has faulty name then also it won't work.

Comment: Also you said the method is called multiple times. Check the last time the method runs where does it go i.e whether in if or else part.

Comment: These images are used in a different UIViewController. They are fine. And as I've said multiple times: I can see these images changing in the memory. I can view their previews and they are correct. But the difference is not shown on the screen. After self.headphonesImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Both Headphones Playing"]; the thing is stuck for some reason.

Comment: Thats really unexpected.

Comment: So I've added a button with a BOOL variable to change the image. And you know, it f#$king works. Method stucks, button works. Some freaking sorcery!

Answer (score 0):

in `VDL`

```
headphonesImagesArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                         @"Both Headphones",
                         @"Both Headphones Playing",
                         nil];
```

And do this :

```
-   (void) toneGeneratorControllerStateHasChangedWithNotification: (NSNotification *) notification
{
       if([notification.name isEqualToString: ToneGenerationHasFinished]) {
           self.headphonesImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed: headphonesImagesArray[0]];
    }
        else {
            self.headphonesImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:headphonesImagesArray[1]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks very shady, but it seems that I've found the solution:

```
-   (void) toneGeneratorControllerStateHasChangedWithNotification: (NSNotification *) notification
{
    BOOL finished = FALSE;
    if([notification.name isEqualToString: ToneGenerationHasFinished])
        finished = TRUE;
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
    ^{
        if(finished)
            [self.headphonesImage setImage: headphonesImagesArray[0]];
        else
            [self.headphonesImage setImage: headphonesImagesArray[1]];
    });
}
```

As far as I know all the UI drawing happens in the main thread. Looks like notification method does not work in the main thread unless you explicitely tell it to do so...